# How to setup a function which gets app settings and sets it as localStorage before the page loads. (next.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, next.js, local-storage

I've been working on a Next.JS web application for the past couple of days but I've reached a problem. The app has an API call (/api/settings) which returns some settings about the application from the database. Currently, I have a function which returns these settings and access to the first component:

```
App.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const settingsRequest = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/settings`
    );
    const settingsResponse = await settingsRequest.json();

    return { settings: settingsResponse };
};
```

This does work and I am able to pass in settings to components but there are two problems with this:

- I need to nest the prop through many components to reach the components that I need
- This request runs every time a page is reloaded/changed

Essentially, I need to create a system that does this:

- runs a function in the `_app.tsx` getInitialProps to check if the data is already in localStorage, if not make the API request and update localStorage
- have the localStorage value accessible from a custom hook.

Right now the problem with this is that I do not have access to localStorage from the `app.tsx` getInitialProps. So if anyone has an alternative to run this function **before** any of the page loads, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: `localstorage` is a browser API and `getInitialProps` runs on server so you just cannot set it from there, you have to `fetch` from client-side to access `localstorage`

Comment: @sairaj what do you mean by fetching localstorage?

Comment: I mean whatever `fetch` call you are making in `getInitialProps` you have to do that from client side, in order to access `localstorage`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it might be a janky solution but I managed to get it working and it might be useful for people trying to achieve something similar:

First we need to create a "manager" for the settings:

```
export const checkIfSettingsArePresent = () => {
    const settings = localStorage.getItem("app_settings");
    if (settings) return true;
    return false;
};

export const getDataAndUpdateLocalStorage = async () => {
    const r = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/settings`);
    const response = await r.json();

    localStorage.setItem("app_settings", JSON.stringify(response));
};
```

With that created we can add a UseEffect hook combined with a useState hook that runs our function.

```
const [doneFirst, setDoneFirst] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const settingsPreset = checkIfSettingsArePresent();
    if (performance.navigation.type != 1)
        if (settingsPreset) return setDoneFirst(true);
    const getData = async () => {
        await getDataAndUpdateLocalStorage();
        setDoneFirst(true);
    };
    getData();
}, []);

//any other logic

if (!doneFirst) {
    return null;
}
```

The final if statement makes sure to not run anything else before the function.

Now, whenever you hot-reload the page, you will see that the localStorage `app_settings` is updated/created with the values from the API.

However, to access this more simply from other parts of the app, I created a hook:

```
import { SettingsType } from "@sharex-server/common";

export default function useSettings() {
    const settings = localStorage.getItem("app_settings") || {
        name: "ShareX Media Server",
    };

    //@ts-ignore
    return JSON.parse(settings) as SettingsType;
}
```

Now I can import useSettings from any function and have access to my settings.